# open app with url-schema but if url have some object don't open app and just open in browser

Tags: swift, url-scheme

I have for example this *URL schema* `test.com` .when I call `test.com://single` or `test.com://all` my application is run and it is ok and good. my problem is if set "alarm" to my url_schema  (`test.com://alarm`), I don't want my app open and only open browser. (if only `alarm` are the *URL schema*  I don't want open my app, just  open browser)
Anybody have a solution for this question
Thank you

Comment: Once your app has opened, within the UIApplicationDelegate function, you can check the URL and then open Safari yourself if you deem it appropriate.

Comment: it's not a bad solution but I want to find a better solution, I want you don't come to my app